# Multiple peak fit - decomposing a graph into visible and hidden peaks of the same probability distribution

Tags: time-series, gamma-distribution, signal-processing, spectral-analysis, chemometrics

I have a graph as a set of coordinates (x, y), where x is a progressing time and y is proportional to an amount of molecules (chromatography results).

Visible peaks on the graph look like of gamma distribution (but not necessarily, could be Weibull, Poison or Normal-skewed).
I need to decompose the graph into multiple signals of **the same** probability distribution (gamma or other),  which are presented either by visible peaks or by internal/hidden ones, located anywhere under graph's curve.

Desired results would look like this:
[image: An example of desired results]

The existence of the internal ones is inferred after fitting distributions to visible peaks first and then calculating differences between the sum of visible peaks fitted models slopes and the original graph curve.

nls() will not work for this problem, since it will miss the internal peaks/signals (besides the fact that it is sensitive to start parameters).

And probably ALS package (or others) would do the job, but I am loosing myself in its input structure and descriptions. My math knowledge is not sufficient.

Looking for some existing elegant solution/tool in R.

Could anybody please advise!

Comment: Do the physical processes of retention and elution suggest particular distributions? I see that depending on the type of dectector you use, the intensity at a given time may be Poisson-distributed as in σ² (I) = E (I). But I guess for I (t) a distribution with continuous t should be chosen).

Comment: The type of distribution is unknown. I would like to build a generic tool in which i could change the distribution formula each time.

Comment: Can you give basic params for a dummy problem?  Pseudocode?  Note: there is a proximity in the peaks where all the samples in the world don't work - the basis is incapable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by basic params. The time on x-axis has a step of 0.02 second, the peaks widths are about several hundred points. Because of the dummy problem, i have tried to fit to each peak gamma distribution separately using optim. But i see that it's sensitive to start params. Posted here some code and params: [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202964/optim-convergence-in-fitting-gamma-distribution-to-separate-peaks-of-time-seri)

Comment: Would you consider the metMUD1 data from the ChemoSpec library to be representative?

Comment: Yes, i guess so. Only i am in a resolution of a single sample (30000 points long).  I don't find a way to put data file here

Comment: I've seen links to dropbox or such.

Comment: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ez1epmbv462aa8r/EngrStudent.1.data?dl=0) is one data example, and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v9d9wui6g3jm2wy/EngrStudent.2.data?dl=0) is another one, just in case. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Question: would you ballpark that at ~30 peaks?  How many components do you expect in the final result?  What do you think typical peak-widths are?  Are you sure the basis is gamma?

Comment: The ballpark is about 60-70 peaks for a sample. Peaks widths may vary from 1 to 30-40 seconds(multiplied by 50 for points amounts) approximately. As for the basis, it's known that it does the job if gamma distribution is assumed, so the main goal is to end up with gamma's shape/scale parameters for each peak. However an option to try other distributions would be very valuable.

Comment: It is enough that the "pick the count and throw it in a pile" can  take a while.  I'm thinking of resampling using an ecdf, then using k-means to find centers then adjust on variances, then use EM.  We will see how it goes.  That is a fairly stiff stack of peaks.  Fun.  Thank you.

Comment: Tremendously appreciate it! 
There is one more thing, which could make fitting to stiff peaks easier.  Since the data didn’t go through baseline correction - each individual discovered gamma signal may start not from the very zero (x-axis), it can start from a step (a delta). 
So eventually each gamma peak should be characterized by: shape, scale and delta.
P.S. 60-70 is the ballpark of total final peaks (visible and internal ones), most likely around 30 of them are the visible ones.

Answer (score 1):

It is called a "finite mixture model".

Here is the first one, by Pearson.

- http://ms.mcmaster.ca/peter/mix/demex/excrabs.html
- http://blog.mrtz.org/2014/04/22/pearsons-polynomial.html

Some general references

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model
- http://repec.org/snasug08/deb_fmm_slides.pdf

Here are libraries for handling it:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/vignettes/flexmix-intro.pdf
- ftp://www.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/mixtools/vignettes/mixtools.pdf
- http://exploringdatablog.blogspot.com/2011/08/fitting-mixture-distributions-with-r.html
- https://www.stat.washington.edu/research/reports/2012/tr597.pdf

Comment: Thanks. These might be usefull tools, the problem is they all are accommodated to a one-dimensional vector of data points as an input. While i have a time-series, meaning that my data is a y-axis coordinates, i have somehow to transform them into a proper vector of points first, in order to apply these tools. I am new in the field, so i know this could sound like a dummy problem to most of the people here.

Comment: It should be an action opposite to density() or hist() function. Could anybody advise please

Comment: The peaks are [Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), not Gaussian.  Starting with the right basis is going to make EM work much more effectively.  Is it okay to smooth the data some first?

Comment: Yes, of course.  May i ask you how did you infer Cauchy is the basis?