# Fitting sums of Gaussian-like density functions

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, signal-processing, chemometrics, constrained-optimization

I acknowledge that [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200540/multiple-peak-fit-decomposing-a-graph-into-visible-and-hidden-peaks-of-the-sam) has been asked a couple years ago, yet it still seems unresolved. Ignoring the domain knowledge, the statistical problem behind is to fit a non-linear regression model under normal error assumptions, which in the simplest case looks like the following (note that $f(x, \underset{\tilde{}} \theta)$ looks like a Gaussian density function with modified standard deviation by polynomials):

$$
Y_i = f(x_i, \underset{\tilde{}} \theta) + \epsilon_i \\
$$

where
$$
f(x, \underset{\tilde{}} \theta) = \theta_1 \exp\{- \frac{1}{2} [\frac{x - \theta_{2}}{\theta_{3} + \theta_{4}(x - \theta_{2}) + \theta_{5}(x - \theta_{2})^2 }]^2 \}  \\   
\epsilon_i \overset{iid}{\sim}   N(0, \sigma^2)\\
x \in [0,1] \\
\theta_1, \theta_3, \theta_5 > 0 \\
\theta_2 \in [0,1] \\
-2\sqrt{\theta_{3}\theta_{5}} < \theta_{4} < 2\sqrt{\theta_{3}\theta_{5}} \\
$$

and moreover, the optimization strategy behind parameter estimation should **easily generalized** to a sum of Gaussian-like functions, that is:

$$
Y_i = \sum_{j=1}^k{f_j(x, \underset{\tilde{}}{\theta_j}) } + \epsilon_i \\
$$

where
$$
f_j(x, \underset{\tilde{}}{\theta_j}) = \theta_{j1} \exp\{- \frac{1}{2} [\frac{x - \theta_{j2}}{\theta_{j3} + \theta_{j4}(x - \theta_{j2}) + \theta_{j5}(x - \theta_{j2})^2 }]^2 \} \\   
\theta_{j1}, \theta_{j3}, \theta_{j5} > 0 \\
\theta_{j2} \in [0,1] \\
-2\sqrt{\theta_{j3}\theta_{j5}} < \theta_{j4} < 2\sqrt{\theta_{j3}\theta_{j5}} \\
$$

Many optimization algorithms that I know of require user-provided initial guesses on parameters. As I will fit the non-linear models many times to many data files, ideally I want to have a more general solution to all files instead of coming up with one initial guess that works well on one data set but poorly on another.

I tried working on the relatively easy case using Gauss-Newton method to estimate parameters and got some trouble.

- parameter estimation is very sensitive to the initial values even in this simple case
- singular matrix when updating $\underset{\tilde{}}{\theta_{t+1}}$ from $\underset{\tilde{}}{\theta_{t}}$
- constraints on $\underset{\tilde{}}{\theta}$ are not accommodated (components of the returned optimized $\hat{\underset{\tilde{}}{\theta}}$ can go out of bound ).

I'm wondering if I should stick to Gauss-Newton method or there are some better methods? Any suggestions are appreciated!